# ApplicationMaster (YARN-Spark) for each job submit?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

*This probably is more like a "theoretical" or "good practices" question rather than strictly practical (no problem with codes, or cluster configuration files).*

So, following this simple scenario:

- Submit via RESt (Apache Livy), say, 10 spark jobs to a YARN-SPARK cluster,
- due to resource management configurations, 5 of them are running and 5 accepted/pending,

would this result in **10 AM instances** running concurrently in the Master node (consuming a lot of ram), right ?

If thats the case, is there any other approach ? Considering this:

- The job requests are fast,
- each time, the cluster would receive almost 1000 requests,
- each job takes an aprox. of 15 secs long to complete (sometimes less depending on the amount of data received to process in each call),
- limited ammount of resources (3 workers with 6gb and 4 cores each + master)

Comment: 5 jobs are running means that 5 instances are running and not 10. Since 5 are busy doing their job, the other 5 jobs are pending for the running jobs to complete as you submitted 10 jobs at once.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if i have correctly understood your question. With separate spark-submit , you mean to invoke separate requests. 
Thus, all requests will go to yarn-scheduler and as per resource availability , they will be in running or submitted or pending state.

Now, we have two ways to submit job on yarn -> client mode and cluster mode.

If you are submitting your jobs in client mode, the driver runs in the client process, and the application master is only used for requesting resources from YARN. So, different  job requests will have different drivers (and associated AMs) created on the same machine. ***This should concern you***.

If you are submitting your jobs in cluster mode, the driver runs inside an application master process which is managed by YARN on the cluster. Thus, different job requests will have different Application Masters(drivers inside) created on different machines.

So, looking at your use-case, it is obvious to use load balancer for large no. of the incoming requests. And submit your jobs in **cluster** mode.
Following it, you can tune your application with best practices properties.

Comment: Right, I am indeed submitting the jobs in **cluster mode** using YARN. So, your recommendation is to place some sort of load balancer in front of the cluster ? Please correct me if I'm wrong, shouldn't Yarn be capable of manage the execution of the submitted jobs, and queue those who can't get resources, without depending on a load balancer ?

Comment: well, the load balancer part comes handy when you are getting request through REST api or so. After having received the request, job is submitted to yarn , that too in cluster mode(as you said). After that yarn should take care of the job sequences as per their resource need. But many times, it does not. The same situation i had faced with yarn , wherein most of the jobs went to pending state, and i had no clue to identify which job went to pending state. So, i applied the following approach: before submitting a job to yarn , i ran a script, that submits job if(memory left > memory req)

Comment: you can use yarn commands to identify those memory status: like `yarn queue -status <your queue name>` will give you details about your queue. Also, `yarn application -list | grep <your queue name>` will give the details of running apps, from where you can get total usage till now. However, to do all these checks , you need to understand the memory requirement of your job. you can start with switching off dynamic allocation property. assign the executors for ex 10, with memory overhead of 512mb (it depends on your job req.), like wise set executor memory and driver memory. And tune it.

Comment: So, the approach is to let the job threads wait until their memory thresholds are available in the job queue. In this way, you will always be in a position wherein you know which of the jobs are waiting, and also you can take an approach where you set some waitTime limit and then your job aborts. and retry after sometime.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I appreciate the explanation, it is very helpful actually. I would try a similar approach to yours in the next days and give some feedback.